# Samba share without authentication Ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: 18.04, samba, authentication

**INTRO**
I'm going through the configuration of a samba standalone server on Ubuntu 18.04.5 server, virtual machine. Shared folders should be accessible without authentication.
Accessing with windows 10 file explorer, credentials are required. Any username accepted, any password accepted. Shared folders are listed.
I would expect credentials are not required.

Details above.

**SERVER SIDE**
Operating system is Ubuntu 18.04 server, installed on virtual machine.

This is my `smb.conf`. According to [samba wiki](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Standalone_Server), this should only allows guest access

```
[global]
    map to guest = Bad User
    log file = /var/log/samba/%m
    log level = 1

[myshare]
    path = /srv/myshare
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = yes

[othershare]
    path = /othershare
    read only = no
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = yes
```

`smb.conf` is validated with `testparm`.

Both shared folders are configured with 777 permissions and owned by root.

Samba is allowed in ufw, anycase ufw is disabled.

Samba version is `4.7.6-Ubuntu`

**CLIENT SIDE**
Operating system is windows 10.

Browsing to the server ip with file explorer, credentials are required. Any username accepted (not empty), any password accepted (empty too). Shared folders are listed.

I also have tried the configuration of user explained in this Q/A, but did not resolve: https://serverfault.com/questions/630631/how-to-make-samba-share-to-not-ask-for-password

**How to disable requiring credentials?**
Thank you